# How to pull messages from a slack channel using python and channel.history

Tags: python, slack-api

I am having trouble with being able to use my API key from slack to pull data from a channel into a dataset. I want to pull messages posted in a channel, and all the tokens I am using are not working and I get KeyErrors in python. I have installed the app, and invited it to the channel. It has been given the following scopes channel.history, groups.history, im.history, mpim.history. this is the code I have so far, can someone please point me in the right direction? I have been lost in reading every document slack has about their API, and I am also still a student and new to this.

```
import os
import slack_sdk
import json
from time import sleep

CHANNEL = "G******"
MESSAGES_PER_PAGE = 200
MAX_MESSAGES = 1000
SLACK_TOKEN = "***************"

client = slack_sdk.WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'])
```

after this last line I get a KeyError: 'SLACK_TOKEN'

maybe I am not using the right API key

Comment: You are trying to read the token from the OS environment variable called `SLACK_TOKEN£`, not the python variable. Try replacing that part with `token=SLACK_TOKEN`

Comment: so instead it should look like this?


```
client = slack_sdk.WebClient(token='SLACK_TOKEN')
```

Comment: and would I be using the bot auth token for this? Or signing secret ? or verification token? I've tried the fix you gave me, and was able to get the Retrieving page 1 response, but then I got the following

 SlackApiError: The request to the Slack API failed. (url: https://www.slack.com/api/conversations.history)
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'channel_not_found'}

So I am not sure what token it is wanting

Comment: In the webclient, you are not specifying anything else than token. Please read the documentation for the `WebClient()`. It should take parameters for channel id, number of messages etc. Pass those parameters properly, like we did the `token=token` above and it should work